# Get rid of broken image in foreach loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, echo

A thumbnail image, `'smallthumb'` is retrieved with [`get_post_meta`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=get_post_meta&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FFunction_Reference%2Fget_post_meta&ei=3oRNT7S0IKec0AXw4KTNAw&usg=AFQjCNEFZkaHJEqlYnt2-qZzgpaSn26PCg) looping an array with `foreach`.

Is it possible to display the image only if there is a thumbnail image? At the moment IE and FF display a broken image if there is no value for the `'smallthumb'` image.

```
<?php
  if(count($ids)){
    echo '<div id=read-more-widget>
    <div class="read-more-header">Read more</div>
    <ul class="read-more-links">';
  foreach($ids as $id){
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a>
    <a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">
    <img class="small-thumb" src="'.get_post_meta( $id, 'smallthumb', true ).'">
    </a><p class="read-more-entry">'.get_post_meta( $id, 'entry', true ).'</p></li>';
    }
  echo "</ul></div>";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how your code works, but would removing the `img` tag alltogether be a viable solution? e.g.

```
<?php
  if(count($ids)){
    echo '<div id=read-more-widget>
    <div class="read-more-header">Read more</div>
    <ul class="read-more-links">';
  foreach($ids as $id){
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a>
    <a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">

    <?php if ($smallthumb = get_post_meta( $id, 'smallthumb', true)) { ?>
      <img class="small-thumb" src="'.$smallthumb.'">
    <?php } ?>

    </a><p class="read-more-entry">'.get_post_meta( $id, 'entry', true ).'</p></li>';
    }
  echo "</ul></div>";
 }
?>
```

The exact solution will need to be updated slightly depending on what `get_post_meta( $id, 'smallthumb', true)` is likely to return.

Comment: Empty string (equals FALSE) in case the field has not value.